# MySQL won't update from PHP - what is possibly wrong with my code?

Tags: php, mysql

Edit:

`$rf` is blank during `if($_POST['email']){` - why though when it's not blank outside of that and how do i fix this?

```
$rf = $_GET['_id'];
//$_GET['_id']; is generated by ME

if ( ! empty($rf))
{
$mysqli->query("UPDATE cse SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE code='" . $rf ."'");
}
//this works. it adds 1 to the counter of clicks column for that referring users row


if($_POST['email']){

    // Requested with AJAX:
    $ajax = ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']  == 'XMLHttpRequest');

    try{
        if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            throw new Exception('Invalid Email!');
        }

        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO cse
                        SET email='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'");

        if($mysqli->affected_rows != 1){
            throw new Exception('exists in the database.');
        } else {   
          $ecode = add_code($mysqli->insert_id); 
        } 
        if(!empty($rf)){
          $mysqli->query("UPDATE cse SET sign_ups = sign_ups + 1 WHERE code='" . $rf ."'");
//this does not work. it should add 1 to the counter of sign_ups column for that referring users row
        }

        if($ajax){
            die(json_encode(array('msg' => $msg)));
        }

    }
    catch (Exception $e){

        if($ajax){
            die(json_encode(array('error'=>$e->getMessage())));
        }

        $msg = $e->getMessage();        
    }
}
```

Edit: For comments below, yes it is already bound in JS

```
$.post("./index.php",{email:$('#email').val()},function(r){

            if(r.error){
                $('#email').val(r.error);
                        } else {
                $('#email').val(r.msg);
            }           
            working = false;
        },'json');
```

Comment: Please use bind variables to avoid security problems.

Comment: Warning: SQL injection vulnerability at `$rf`. Is `$_POST['email']` set?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Yup it's entered by the user, just ran a test. How can I fix the SQL injection vulnerability?

Comment: INSERT isn't combined with SET in standard SQL: INSERT INTO cse (email) VALUES ('".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."')" would be standard syntax

Comment: example of what? SQL injection? `mypage.php?_id=' or ''='`

Comment: Are you sure that $_POST['email'] isn't empty?

Comment: @Mark:Who said that _it is not combined_, We can

Comment: @Mark Baker: Only if the email does not exist, and the refer is not NULL, I then want the referrer to have signups+1

Comment: @roe: how can I prevent that? @Belinda: I've just tested and it's not empty. thanks

Comment: Is it possible that there is a typo in your column name and if not is sign_ups defined as a numeric field in your schema?

Comment: @Belinda: Nope no typo and sign_ups is set as an integer with 64 length, default of 0?

Comment: @Shakti Singh - I stand corrected, can you tell me when it was incorporated into the ANSI or ISO standards? I can't find it, even in SQL:2008.

Comment: @Mark: As your initial comment was something different that does not contain the _"in standard SQL"_. See the second syntax of INSERT here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: Can you add the schema of your `cse` table to your post please? It might help debug. In terms of preventing mysql injection either use parametirised queries. If you are expecting `$_GET['_id']` to be a number use `is_numeric` to check for that. Otherwise escape it with `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: @Belinda: Updated question, should provide some sort of answer. Just require it to do another if statement (which then breaks the code) to check if referrer is blank, if so, don't run the UPDATE. How can I set the `if ( ! empty($rf)){}` in that second part of my question?

Comment: Hmmm it worked ONCE, has now stopped working.. unless I updated the code by mistake and re-uploaded..

Comment: Is the `insert` occurring? Are you sure it's returning 1 row affected so that you're not bailing out on the `throw`?

Comment: @jswolf19: it shouldn't be returning 1 row affected..

Comment: What does your table structure look like? Because if for instance your code field is required (ie has a NOT NULL constraint) then it will probably raise an exception when you try inserting a row without one. And where's the rest of your code? I see a `try` but no `catch`, so this code shouldn't even run as-is.

Comment: @wimvds, actually, you don't even see the end of the `if($_POST['email']){` block.

Comment: @wimvds: updated code to include catch. field is sign_ups, type is int(64), Not Null, Default is 0

Comment: @wimvds: code field is NULL and NULL by default

Comment: @CarpeNoctumDC: Any thoughts on this one? You helped with the code last time :) Registered new user on here as I lost my previous one.

Comment: @Belinda: you were almost spot on!! $rf is blank during `if($_POST['email']){` - why though when it's not blank outside of that and how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Given that none of the numerous comments above have pointed out the obvious - you have no error checking on your queries. If a mysqli query fails, it returns FALSE. If the query succeeds, it returns either TRUE or a result object.

instead of just guessing at what the problem is, why not do the obvious and let mysql tell you exactly what the problem is. Using the following logic everywhere you run a query will make debugging this problem far easier:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE cse SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE code='" . $rf ."'");
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die("Mysql error: " . $mysqli->error);
}
```

Remember - there's only one way for a query succeed, and many many ways for them to fail, even if the SQL statement you're executing is syntactically correct.

Comment: @Marc B: great idea - it went through fine.. no error :( still no update though.

Comment: @Marc B: If I place your code (tailored for the sign_ups), before `if($_POST['email']){` it goes through and works perfectly! it's only when I place it within the `try` it won't update..

Comment: You should do this sort of check after every query, not just the one I indicated in my sample. Every query can potentially fail, so you have to check every time.

Comment: @Marc B: Any other possibilities?

Comment: Slap some debugging output into the script for each stage it goes through. Dump out variable contents, locator strings ("now doing query X", "checking if email is ok", etc...) and basically work through the script line-by-line to see if it's working as expected.

Comment: @Marc B: AHA! $rf is blank during `if($_POST['email']){` - why though when it's not blank outside of that and how do i fix this?